# How to create a Custom Data Source in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How to create a custom Data Source in google analytics. I found this in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubl9O4eOQQs, But Is this feature deprecated in version 3?

Comment: You now find this in Admin->Property Settings (middle column) -> Data Import (next to last item). Not really on-topic, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customDataSource can be found in Admin->Property Settings -> Data Importdata import->new Data set with following options.

- user data
- campaign data
- content data
- geography data
- content data
- product data
- custom data